# XCode4, Saving the File

Tags: c++, xcode

I have created several files on XCode4, which I would like to rename. (C++ Programming)

However, there is no 'Save As' and when I have renamed the file on my 'Documents', it then cannot open/run the correct file.

Really stupid question, but does anyone know how to rename the file while keeping the code etc. the same? (Short of copy and pasting the code into an appropriately named document).

Thanks

Comment: Just double klick on the file in xcode...

Comment: That does absolutely nothing, bar open the file

Comment: Click once and wait 2 seconds lol

Comment: Again nothing happens. What are you even referring to? Click what part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save as? Just create new file and rename.

In Xcode4, you can easily rename files.

```
« Click on file
« Select show utility
« Rename file.
```

See image for clear information.[image]